# append OrderedDict in JSON

Tags: python

I want to append some variables in OrderedDict() in python.
Here is my example

```
cm = 190
kg = 90
group = OrderedDict()
group['cate'] = OrderedDict()
group['cate']['cm'] = cm
group['cate']['kg'] = kg
group['task'] = []
dict = OrderedDict()
for i in range(3):
    dict[label] = []
    dict[label].append(OrderedDict([("name:", 'lala')]))
```

Above example works well(maybe above codes not works) , but when I try to assign variable in name

```
lala = 'lala'
dict[label].append(OrderedDict([("name:", lala)]))
```

It occurs 'not a serialized' error.

How can I add lala instead of 'lala'?

Comment: Can you please add complete error message? Your second example works fine for me. You mentioned JSON in your question title, add that relevant code too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the question since it seems obvious. Does this answer your question ?

```
    from collections import OrderedDict
    lala=[1,2,3]
    d = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(3):
        label='toto'+str(i)
        d[label] = []
        d[label].append(OrderedDict([("name:", lala)]))
```